# How to change the appearance of the best fit line in R

Tags: r, plot, regression

I am trying to add a polynomial best fit line but for some reason, it appears to be drawn back and forth on the plot. I was wondering what I should do to fix the line

[image]

```
yhat_pol = lm(age~poly(height,2), data = Loblolly)
yhat_lin = lm(age~height, data = Loblolly)

plot(x=Loblolly$height, y=Loblolly$age, pch=16, xlab = "Height (ft)", ylab = "Age (yr)", main = "Height vs Age of Loblloy Pine Trees")
lines(Loblolly$height, predict(yhat_pol), type="l", col="green", lwd=2)
lines(Loblolly$height, predict(yhat_lin), type="l", col="red", lwd=2)
lines(sort(Loblolly$height), fitted(yhat_lin)[order(Loblolly$height)])
legend("topleft", 
        legend = c("linear","polynomial"), 
        col = c("red","green"),
        lty = 1, lwd=3)
```

|  | height | age | Seed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4.51 | 3 | 301 |
| 15 | 10.89 | 5 | 301 |
| 29 | 28.72 | 10 | 301 |
| 43 | 41.74 | 15 | 301 |
| 57 | 52.70 | 20 | 301 |
| 71 | 60.92 | 25 | 301 |
| 2 | 4.55 | 3 | 303 |
| 16 | 10.92 | 5 | 303 |
| 30 | 29.07 | 10 | 303 |
| 44 | 42.83 | 15 | 303 |

Comment: Could you share some of the data used in your question? Try `dput(Loblolly)` or `dput(head(Loblolly))`.

Comment: I got the dataset from the dataset package in R so, I think just typing in Loblolly should work but I added the head(Loblolly) to the question.

Comment: You're right! Forget about my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't ask for it, but here is - as pointed out by Brian Montgomery - a solution using `ggplot2`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)


Loblolly %>%
  mutate(age_pred_pol = predict(yhat_pol),
         age_pred_lin = predict(yhat_lin)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = height, y = age)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = age_pred_pol, color = "Polynomial Best Fit")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = age_pred_lin, color = "Linear Best Fit")) +
  labs(x = "Height (ft)", y = "Age (yr)", title = "Height vs Age of Loblloy Pine Trees") +
  scale_colour_manual(name = "Prediction",
                      breaks = c("Polynomial Best Fit", "Linear Best Fit"),
                      values = c("red", "green")) +
  theme_bw()
```

This returns

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You almost had it.

```
lines(sort(Loblolly$height), predict(yhat_pol)[order(Loblolly$height)], type="l", col="green", lwd=2)
```

I don't think the order of the data causes these problems if you use ggplot2.
[image]